# How do I align text to the left of my Textinput in react Native?

Tags: react-native

I am working on the UI to my login screen. I have tried wrapping the elements differently, someone suggested using Multi-Line I tried that as well.

With standard React/JS / css /html I have no issues doing this. But I cannot seem to figure this one out.  I try not to ask for help and figure it out on my own to learn but I have been stuck for around 3 hours and I really want to move on.

Here is my component for my LoginPageUI:

```
export const LoginPageUI = () => {
const [userName, setUserName] = useState("")
const [password, setPassword] = useState("")

return (
  <>
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View style={LoginUIStyles.input}>
        <Text style={LoginUIStyles.outerText}>UserName</Text>
        <TextInput
          multiline={true}
          style={LoginUIStyles.inputField}
          placeholder="Enter Your UserName"
          onChangeText={(text) => setUserName(text)}
          value={userName}
        ></TextInput>
      </View>
      <TextInput
        style={LoginUIStyles.input}
        placeholder="Password"
        onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
        value={password}
      ></TextInput>
    </SafeAreaView>
  </>
);
```

Here is my style.

````
export const LoginUIStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  inputContainer: {
    width: "80%",
  },
  input: {
    flexDirection: "row", // Place text and input side by side
    alignItems: "center", // Center items vertically
    height: 40,
    borderColor: "gray",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 5,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  outerText: {
    flex: 1, 
  },
  inputField: {
    flex: 3, 
  },
});```


I attached a photo of what it looks like currently. I was able to get it to go left in the textInput, however I can't seem to get it outside of the textInput and beside it.




wrapping and moving elements,

multiLine,

using the React-Native Docs for support.
````

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your text has already been aligned to the left-hand side of your `TextInput`. So, what is causing the appearance of that text to be still within the borders of the `TextInput` component is due to the css properties of `LoginUIStyles.input`.

It is noticed that you have housed the `Text` component and the `TextInput` component under one `View` component. If you move its css border properties over to `LoginUIStyles.inputField` from `LoginUIStyles.input`, that text should now appear to be outside of the `TextInput` component like this:

[image: this]